# Can not download 32 bit SWT on a 64bit system

Tags: java, download, swt

Maybe it sounds a little bit curious but I'm not be able to download the 32bit version of SWT. If I go to the eclipse website and SWT home and click the Windows link there, I will only get the swt-4.5-win32-win32-x86_64.zip what is the version for 64bit systems. That's clear because I'm using Windows 64bit.
But I also need the 32bit SWT for distribution reasons. But I found no list or whatever to select the download version. It seems that the download process automatically detects the current OS and then only offers the zip file for this one.

Answer (score 0):

**x86** stands for **32-bit** so you're all good by downloading the file you've mentioned

Comment: Does the zip contains dlls for both platforms in the same package? And why I get the UnsatisfiedLinkError if I try to start my SWT application?

Comment: As far as i know it has to consist of dlls for both platforms as it's label indicated that it could be used for both x86 which is 32-bit and x64 which is 64-bit platforms,about the error i could be more helpful if i know some details i suppose

Comment: @altralaser No, the x86 download is for a 32 bit JRE only (it is the JRE that matters). The x86_64 download is for a 64 bit JRE only.

Comment: @greg-449 is it possible if one uses a 32-bit JRE on a 64-bit OS then?

Comment: You can use 32 bit SWT with a 32 bit JRE on a 64 bit Windows system.

Comment: so if this guy use a 32-bit JRE would it be possible for him/her to download a 32-bit package from the website? in case it is possible what would be with 64-bit version? which version should he use ?

Comment: @greg-449: Yes that was also my opinion. My problem is that I installed the 32bit JRE but can't find the 32bit SWT on the eclipse home.

Comment: This answer is correct, the x86 build is 32 bit, x86_64 is 64 bit. Both are listed on the main download page for the Eclipse Project - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.5.1-201509040015/

Comment: @greg-449: Sorry, it was my mistake. I only saw the downloads for eclipse and because I didn't want to download the IDE I not scrolled down the page.